# check if event target is a jquery stored variable

Tags: jquery

```
<div>

  <h1 class="h1 myh1">Headline</h1>

</div>

(function($){
    var var_h1 = $('h1') 
    $('div').on('click', function(event){
    if (event.target == var_h1 ) {
        alert('H1 was clicked')
    }
  })
})(jQuery)
```

When I click h1 nothing is happening.

How can I use `event.target` and check if the element clicked is the variable `var_h1`?

I don't wish to check a class if exist because this variable will be reused again and again. How can I using `event.target` check for the variable `var_h1` if clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant compare objects with == successfully unless they are *the same* object. jquery objects are not the same as dom elements.

Comment: so using `var_h1` how can I do this, I mean check if `var_h1` is clicked?

Comment: Test whether or not the jquery collection contains the clicked element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is the comparison:

```
event.target == var_h1
```

`var_h1` is a jQuery **object**, not a native HTML element reference. So instead you need:

```
event.target === var_h1[0]
```

or

```
event.target === var_h1.get(0)
```

Comment: thanks :))) will approve this answer in 10 min :))))